# Why does the Stack Exchange network not have a thumbnail image when a question/answer is posted on Reddit?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, reddit

When something from the Stack Exchange network [is posted on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/domain/stackexchange.com/), it just gets this default question mark thumbnail image:

[image: Reddit default thumbnail image]

Other sites get nice thumbnails. Is there something you guys could do or is it something that must be done on Reddit's side?

---

### UPDATE:

I just posted [this link on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/19byyo/til_there_is_actual_canon_proof_that_smurf_blood/) and was surprised to see a thumbnail image linked to it:

[image: Reddit Snapshot]

The image is the third image on the [linked question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/27034/45), and I don't see anything special with it.

Looking to the link [I posted first above](http://www.reddit.com/domain/stackexchange.com/), I found [this other link](http://www.reddit.com/r/hiddenvalue/comments/19agog/electronics_you_can_scavange_fpgas_from/) to electronics.stackexchange:

[image: Reddit Snapshot 2]

This time, the image appears to be taken from [a Community Promotion Ad](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2537/19500)!

This is probably worse than getting the Reddit default thumbnail image. Did something change?

Comment: Heh, I'd look up if there's special HTML like Facebook's *image_src* meta definition to make that work, but I can't seem to find any help links anywhere on that site. So I'm just gonna mark it a fail and move on.

Comment: @jeremytunnell You tagged it *status-completed*, what was done exactly?

Comment: Default image will just be the site logo.   No reason we shouldn't have something, and it only took about 30 seconds to make the change.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell Great job, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will go out in a build later today.

Comment: Finally, it's awesome to have this feature, thanks guys!

Comment: look like it does not work very well, [my last post](http://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/19he3b/til_that_according_to_some_clues_in_the_book_the/#) show my gravatar as the thumbnails!

Answer (score 17):

According to *[Ticket #287 (Add a standard for pulling thumbnails)](http://code.reddit.com/ticket/287)*, Reddit uses the Facebook method to derive thumbnails. Stack Exchange could add

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://URL-TO-YOUR-IMAGE" / >
```

to the head section of the page to specify an image to be used as the thumbnail.

I don't know why none of the images already on the page are being selected (it's supposed to traverse the DOM to look for other image links), but the [source code](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/scraper.py) is on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) if anyone wants to take a look.

Comment: The site's logo and many other graphics on the site are CSS sprites so they'll be ignored. The only other pictures on most pages are users' avatars: IIRC there's a minimum size requirement for the thumbnail spider, and these fall below it. I hope SEI does add that `<link>` tag pointing to a logo; links shared on Facebook always look a bit lame without it.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Aha!  That's right, I forgot that even the logo is a CSS sprite.  I wonder if posts that include an image hosted on imgur get a proper thumbnail on reddit and Facebook?  (I don't want to submit a link to reddit just to test, but I can check FB later.)

Comment: Not sure about Reddit, but [submitting *this* post to Facebook does have an amusing result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oqVix.png).

Comment: @BilltheLizard No for reddit, yes for Facebook. see [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/z006w/til_darth_vaders_control_panel_has_hebrew/).

Comment: At least the Apple Touch icon is still not a sprite

Comment: Adding an other link to the Apple Touch icon in the head section could be a quick solution. I just hope it will be done.

Comment: Ticket 287 link is now broken.

Comment: `<link rel="image_src"` still works and was moved from `scraper.py` to `/r2/r2/lib/media.py`  https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/8bdc62314a970d27f6aef86adc427186e421ca08/r2/r2/lib/media.py#L386-389 so does `<meta property="og:image" content="http://link.to/image.png" />` see also related facebook info http://stackoverflow.com/a/4101909/1754875 and