# Incorrect icon used by Facebook when pasting links

Tags: feature-request, facebook

**Note**: This is a misfeature of **Facebook**, but consideration might be given by StackExchange to working around it.

If someone discusses a topic on Facebook that is covered by a Stackexchange question, I will cut and paste the URL into a comment.

Facebook, in its urge to provide visual clues, automatically looks for some image to include with the link to act as a preview.

In practice, the first image it finds is the avatar of the last person to *edit* the question. As much as I think we should acknowledge the fine work of the editors, this is not an appropriate image to go with the question.

<strike>I do not know the rules Facebook uses to select an image. I do not know if Facebook publish a mechanism for site-owners to provide an appropriate image.</strike> Facebook has published [how to indicate the appropriate image](https://www.facebook.com/notes/hyperarts-web-design/set-up-your-website-to-control-images-text-in-facebook-status-update-links/10150320031290844).

It would be nice for the selected image to be the icon appropriate to the site, not a cartoon picture of a random user.

> **Related question:** [Why does the Stack Exchange network not have a thumbnail image when a question/answer is posted on Reddit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147631/why-does-the-stack-exchange-network-not-have-a-thumbnail-image-when-a-question-a)

Comment: The same issue occurred with reddit a while back IIRC... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147631/why-does-the-stack-exchange-network-not-have-a-thumbnail-image-when-a-question-a

Comment: @Richard: Excellent find as it points out FB's rules and interface. I have added it to the question. Thanks.

Comment: It might also apply to search engine indexing?

Comment: This is a dupe of the majority of posts on FSO :-P og:image FTW

Comment: @Lix: Example links or it didn't happen.... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow should serve a working `<og:image>` to fix this.

Comment: To start with, I suggest you monitor your tone. It can be difficult to convey emotions over text, but this comes across as rather rude and condescending. Remember the "Be Nice" policy.

Comment: "Facebook selection of images works as it should." No, FB works as FB says it should. It can be a bug-free implementation of a defined standard, and still be a misfeature. FB is selecting an inappropriate image from a site that has not offered a preferred one. The selection of an inappropriate image is a misfeature. The fact the Stack Exchange does not conform to an optional standard does not change this.

Comment: Misfeature based on your assumption and perspective. Is Facebook scraper sentient? No.

Comment: "This is not how Facebook selects images. This is your assumption." Yes, and I initially stated that I did not know how it worked. That  it chooses the first large-enough image rather than the first image says to me I made a pretty good guess.

Comment: I linked to the HyperArts site as evidence that a standard had been published. Any tutorial or description would have sufficed. I didn't intend to claim it was the official standard.

Comment: You cannot call it a misfeature when all the only intent of image preview is to show an image from the link selected.

Comment: your sentence states it as "Facebook have published how to indicate the appropriate image." then you link to a random page, come on @_@

Comment: "Misfeature based on your assumption and perspective." Yes. I don't apologise for that. "Is Facebook scraper sentient? No." Strawman. FB could simply choose NOT to illustrate with an image if the page doesn't conform to the standard.

Comment: You can go down the road of I'm rude, w/e. Your question is entirely based on incorrect statements and assumptions. I'm highlighting to you that.

Comment: I think I should disengage at this point. You are trolling.

Comment: Again your lack of knowledge of how Facebook scraper works impedes your actual argument. Facebook offers the choice not to show the image it's called "remove preview". ` FB could simply choose NOT to illustrate with an image if the page doesn't conform to the standard` and it does, again your lack of knowledge as well as overlooking the image reference above from the debugger is amazing. Facebook provided an image that met the standard.

Comment: *"it's not enough to be right. You also have to be a dick about it!"* Could this answer not be condensed down to "Stack Overflow should serve a working `<og:image>`"?

Comment: Would be nice if someone could point out the rude parts

Comment: @odd - ignoring for a second the tone of the post, it's content *is* correct. Facebook just scrapes the URL it was provided and displays what it has retrieved. It's the URL's author that is in charge of manipulating the data contained within the URL in such a way that Facebook will "see what they want to be seen". This includes using the `og:meta` tags.

Comment: @phw - I think the main misinterpretation of tone was a result of your choice of structure. The whole [**FALSE**](http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/35276185.jpg), and [**INCORRECT**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HyPZp.png) format and also the bolding...